# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ex' was corrupted

Tags: c++, mysql, runtime-error, stack-corruption

I get the run time exception;

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ex' was corrupted.

for the following piece of code.

```
DBConnPtr CDBConnector::GetConnectionInstance()
{
    if (m_pConn)
       return m_pConn;

    if (m_loginInfo.hostName.IsEmpty() || 
        m_loginInfo.portNumber == 0 || 
        m_loginInfo.userName.IsEmpty())
      return m_pConn;

    CString hostInfo(_T(""));
    hostInfo.Format("tcp://%s:%d", m_loginInfo.hostName, m_loginInfo.portNumber);
    sql::SQLString host = hostInfo;
    sql::SQLString user = m_loginInfo.userName;
    sql::SQLString pwd = m_loginInfo.userPwd;

    try
    {
        sql::Driver* pDriver = get_driver_instance();
        m_pConn = (DBConnPtr)pDriver->connect(host, user, pwd);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException ex)
    {
    }
    //mysql_thread_end();

    return m_pConn;
}
```

Before moving `sql::SQLString pwd = m_loginInfo.userPwd;` outside the try block, it used to throw

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pwd' was corrupted.

Any ideas why?
Im using mysql library and trying to catch SQLException that happens at the `connect` call.

### EDIT

Output Window after typecasting every CString to LPCTSTR:

> First-chance exception at 0x75B61D4D in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x0493F8C0.
>   First-chance exception at 0x75B61D4D in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x0493F8C0.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x005E18A5 in MyApp.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Comment: From `m_loginInfo.hostName.IsEmpty()` I conclude that `m_loginInfo.hostName` is of type `CString`. `CString`s must be explicitly cast to `LPCTSTR` before passing to `CString::Format`. Though, I do not see how that might corrupt the stack. You might look into `get_driver_instance` to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) points out: When you pass a character string as an optional argument, you must cast it explicitly as LPCTSTR.

Also, this [article](http://mfctips.com/2012/03/23/cstringformat-s-cstring-argument-garbage-text/) points out the consequence if you don't do so.

If the type SQLString can be cast to LPCTSTR, change this line:

```
hostInfo.Format("tcp://%s:%d", m_loginInfo.hostName, m_loginInfo.portNumber);
```

to:

```
hostInfo.Format(_T("tcp://%s:%d"), LPCTSTR(m_loginInfo.hostName), LPCTSTR(m_loginInfo.portNumber));
```

Comment: It simply wouldn't compile if TCHAR were defined WCHAR.

Comment: A different error this time; `Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.` After typecasting. @AndreyChernyakhovskiy

Comment: You should make sure that SQLString can be casted first.